# android.widget.Button does not have setOnClickListener method

Tags: java, android

I am totally new at Android and Android Studio. I am trying to write very simple application with a Button:
here is my code:
{

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is the i am getting error "cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener" and the setOnClickListener appear at red.
when i am trying to do auto completion of setOnClickListener at part of addButton, it appears that addBurron does not have this method.

can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Button.setOnClickListener()
```

with:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener()
```

you must set the listener to the object `addButton` and not the class `Button`.
Also this code:

```
Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
});
```

must be placed inside a method like `onCreate()`.